# Unique LU factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

we know that the theorem that establish existence and uniqueness of LU factorization, state that

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}_{n^n}$. The LU factorization of $A$ with $l_{i,i}=1$ exists and is unique if and only if its principal minors up to order $n-1$ are not singular.

Now I am considering the following matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 4& 2\\
5& 0& 3\\
4 &7 &9
\end{pmatrix}$

So according to the theorem the LU factorization should fail to exist or be unique, as the entry $a_{2,2}$ (seen as a sub matrix of order 1) is zero. I found an LU factorization but I cannot see that it is not unique. Could anyone help? Did I misunderstood the theorem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The LU factorization exists iff all *leading principal* minors are nonsingular, ie. those made by a $k\times k$ upper left corner of the matrix. And if it exists then it is unique.

Comment: A good reference regarding this would be the subsection titled **Existence and uniqueness** in the Wiki:[LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)

Answer (score 1):

The "leading principal minors" for your matrix are

$$D_1 = 1$$

$$D_2 = \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 4 \\ 5 & 0 \end{array} \right| = -20 $$

and

$$D_3 = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 4 & 2 \\ 5 & 0 & 3 \\ 4 & 7 & 9 \end{array} \right| = -83 $$

and since all of them are non-zero, the LU decomposition exists.

Comment: I see. I did not notice that in the definition of sub matrix, it was requested that the indexes have to contiguous. So, the definition of principal sub matrix agrees. Thank you.